# Apply for loop to filter rows for several columns and store filtered data to list - R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, filter, paste

Imagine that I have a dataframe `df` with 4 columns (`colA`, `colB`, `colC`, and `key`). `key` is a column that will be potentially useful as input for merging the processed data (this part is not shown in the example code below). The dataframe has negative values and positive values above 100. However, I would like to filter rows that are only positive and only have values below 100, for the columns `colA`, `colB`, and `colC`. The filtered data should be assigned to a variable describing the column (e.g. `new_df$colA`). Thereafter, the variable should be stored in the list `new`. While running the for loop, I am faced with an error:

```
Error in paste0("new", column, sep = "_") = df[column < 100 & column >  : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

It wouldn't surprise me if the `$` character causes issues - however I am not able to tackle this problem. The relevant code:

```
df <- data.frame(colA=c(-10, 30, 50, 60, 102),
                 colB=c(60, 200, 70, -4, 60),
                 colC=c(400, 300, 10, 230, 2))

#create column with unique key to potentially merge processed data on
df$key <- seq(1, nrow(df))

#initialize list with columns that relate to dataframe - every column should be used for filtering data
columns = list(df$colA, df$colB, df$colC)

#create empty list where processed data can be stored to 
new = list()

#loop 
for(column in columns){
  #create dataframe of relevant column only and key for later data processinh
  df <-  data.frame(column,df$key)
  #select only rows that meet conditions
  paste0("new", column, sep="_") = df[column < 100 & column > 0, ]
  #append new data to list 'new'
  new = c(new, paste0("new", column, sep="_"))
}
```

The expected output is

```
colA = 30, 50, 60
colB = 60, 70, 60
colC = 10, 2
```

Comment: Do you want `for(nm in names(df)) {x <- df[[nm]]; print(paste(nm, '=', toString(x[x < 100 & x > 0])))}` or `lapply(df, function(x) x[x <100 & x > 0])`

Comment: Depends on how easy it is to store the processed data for both methods - that is not included in your suggested methods?

Comment: The second option returns the output as a `list` which you can store `new <- lapply(df, function(x) x[x <100 & x > 0])`  For the first option. you may need to create a list to sstore i.e. `new <- vector('list', ncol(df)); names(new) <- names(df); for(nm in names(df)) {x <- df[[nm]]; new[[nm]] <-paste(nm, '=', toString(x[x < 100 & x > 0]))}`

Comment: @akrun Is there also an easy way to link the values with the specific key? For example, the value 50 of colA should have key 3